# How to hide the legend in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

Hi, I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I am trying to make invisible this things whatever it names, i don't know. How can i delete this things in the red rectangle.

I found the answer somehow.

```
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is the `Legend`.

You can hide or show it with the following code:

```
Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(false); // hide legend
```

By default, it is shown.